# Wait for asyncronous event with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

I have two radio buttons and one text box. Every time I switch the radio button the text box is cleared.

Following sequence:

1. text box is empty
2. I switch the radio button (Selenium IDE: click -> radioButton)
3. I input some text in the text box (Selenium IDE: type -> textBox)

Problem:
The input for text box is done before clear of radio button takes place. So everytime I input something in the text box the input is deleted after a short period of time.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Share code snippet of how you have implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a "Pause" command after clicking on the radio button

```
Command: pause
Target: 3000 (or as applicable)
Value:
```

This way your execution will wait for 3 seconds, and hopefully the text box will be cleared when you get to the "SendKeys" step.

PS. Try using webdriver with your language preference.

Comment: Pause works. But I thought there is a more clever way. Is there a more clever way than pause if I use webdriver?

Comment: yes sure, There's Explicit waiting approach, where you can explicitly set what are you waiting to happen. In your case you will wait until the text box is empty and then you'll continue to next step.

Comment: This shouldn't work because the textbox is also empty before switching the radio button.

Comment: @gartenkralle I guess you must be waiting for a certain event since you need "asych" approach. So whatever that event is that should be your explicit wait.